# Function array.find() for render url `${item}` react native not working

Tags: arrays, react-native

I am trying to use a specific value(video) from an array to render it in a url like this `${video_id}`.

The problem is that it won't get the value from the video. I use a var video_id and setting it to the video value from the array.

I have tried the find function and set it to a var. Is there any other way that works?

**Example of array:**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Task2",
        "description": "Description task 2 goes here",
        "video": "L-YWx_x6ksI",
        "done": false,
        "steps": [

        ],
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

DailyTask.js

```
class DailyTaskScreen extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: true,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      taskDone: false,
      task: [],
      steps: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    fetch('https://api.taskoftheday.com/daily-ecommerce/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token xxxxxx`
      }
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( jsonRes => this.setState({ task: jsonRes }) )
    .then(console.log(this.state.task))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))

    fetch(`https://api.taskoftheday.com/step/?task_id=${this.state.task}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token xxxxxx`
      }
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( jsonRes => this.setState({ steps: jsonRes }) )
    .then(console.log(this.state.steps))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))
  }

 render() {

 var video_id = this.state.task.find(function(video) {
      return video;
    });

    return (
      <>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: 300 }} >
          <>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.ShowHideComponent}>{
              this.state.appState == 'active' &&
              <WebView
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                useWebKit={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                source={{ uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video_id}?playsinline=1&fs=1&modestbranding=0&rel=0&` }}
              />
            }
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </>
    );

  }

}
```

I want to display the video value from the array in the youtube url.

Comment: post example of `jsonRes` that you receive

Comment: [
    {
        "title": "Task2",
        "description": "Description task 2 goes here",
        "video": "L-YWx_x6ksI",
        "done": false,
        "steps": [

        ],
        "id": 2
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) description. It works by running your callback function (the one you pass as an argument) on every array item, and the first item to return truthy value is the result of .find. It is used to find elements inside the array, and it's not what you need

Since your state.steps is an array of objects of form `{title: '...', description: '...', ...}` you want to take a first item of array and then the `video` property of that item

```
const video_id = this.state.task[0].video
```